# Sencha touch mainView push/pop strange behaviour after pushing 5 forms

Tags: extjs, touch

I'm building account system using sencha touch (architect) and now I have an issue where the code executed but the `this.getMainView().pop();` NOT and the view states on current one !

my views:

**Login scrn-->  cstmrs list-->       cstmr details-->         rceipt-->           checks**

- When I get to receipt view (without checks) the code executed and auto returned to   customer's details view.
- But soon I click to add a check to the receipt (only displaying the form without any code) the check view injected to mainview after that I click back button to return to receipt window, but now when I click save button the receipt is saved and the data arrives server side ok, but the big problem the `this.getMainView().pop();` doesn't work or doesn't executed !!
- Is there any wrong with my code? it works without displaying the 'checks' form !
- Nothing in firebug/chrome debugger

I use this code to show forms:

```
var mainView=this.getMainView();
mainView.push({xtype: "frmChcks",title:'new check'});
```

And this code for getting back:

```
this.getMainView().pop();
```

Thank you in advice

Comment: I removed all code in save button (in receipt) except: **this.getMainView().pop();** But works only in SECOND click !

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh it was because I used a hidden field called 'id', don't use 'id' for you components :-)